# In F#, is there a functional way to converting a flat array of items into an array of a group of items?

Tags: f#

In F#, imagine we have an array of bytes representing pixel data with three bytes per pixel in RGB order:

```
[| 255; 0;   0; //Solid red
   0;   255; 0; //Solid green
   0;   0;   255; //Solid blue
   1;   72;  9; 
   34;  15;  155
... |]
```

I'm having a hard time knowing how to functionally operate on this data as-is, since a single item is really a consecutive block of *three* elements in the array.

So, I need to first group the triples in the array into something like this:

```
[| 
   [| 255; 0;   0   |];
   [| 0;   255; 0   |];
   [| 0;   0;   255 |];
   [| 1;   72;  9   |];
   [| 34;  15;  155 |]
... |]
```

Now, gathering up the triples into sub-arrays is easy enough to do with a for loop, but I'm curious--**is there a functional way to gather up groups of array elements in F#?** My ultimate goal is not simply to convert the data as illustrated above, but to solve the problem in a more declarative and functional manner. But I have yet to find an example of how to do this without an imperative loop.

Comment: I updated my answer with a sequence-based approach, if that's of any use to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kvb's answer may not give you what you want. `Seq.windowed` returns a *sliding* window of values, e.g., `[1; 2; 3; 4]` becomes `[[1; 2; 3]; [2; 3; 4]]`. It seems like you want it split into contiguous chunks. The following function takes a list and returns a list of triples (`'T list -> ('T * 'T * 'T) list`).

```
let toTriples list = 
  let rec aux f = function
    | a :: b :: c :: rest -> aux (fun acc -> f ((a, b, c) :: acc)) rest
    | _ -> f []
  aux id list
```

Here's the inverse:

```
let ofTriples triples =
  let rec aux f = function
    | (a, b, c) :: rest -> aux (fun acc -> f (a :: b :: c :: acc)) rest
    | [] -> f []
  aux id triples
```

#### EDIT

If you're dealing with huge amounts of data, here's a sequence-based approach <strike>with constant memory use</strike> (all the `option`s and `tuple`s it creates have a negative impact on GC--see below for a better version):

```
let (|Next|_|) (e:IEnumerator<_>) =
  if e.MoveNext() then Some e.Current
  else None

let (|Triple|_|) = function
  | Next a & Next b & Next c -> Some (a, b, c) //change to [|a;b;c|] if you like
  | _ -> None

let toSeqTriples (items:seq<_>) =
  use e = items.GetEnumerator()
  let rec loop() =
    seq {
      match e with
      | Triple (a, b, c) -> 
        yield a, b, c
        yield! loop()
      | _ -> ()
    }
  loop()
```

#### EDIT 2

ebb's question about memory use prompted me to test and I found `toSeqTriples` to be slow and cause surprisingly frequent GCs. The following version fixes those issues and is almost 4x faster than the list-based version.

```
let toSeqTriplesFast (items:seq<_>) =
  use e = items.GetEnumerator()
  let rec loop() =
    seq {
      if e.MoveNext() then
        let a = e.Current
        if e.MoveNext() then 
          let b = e.Current
          if e.MoveNext() then
            let c = e.Current
            yield (a, b, c)
            yield! loop()
    }
  loop()
```

This has relatively constant memory usage vs a list or array-based approach because a) if you have a `seq` to start with the entire sequence doesn't have to be slurped into a list/array; and b) it also returns a sequence, making it lazy, and avoiding allocating yet another list/array.

Comment: You're welcome. You can, of course, use `List.ofArray`/`List.toArray` for converting the input/output.

Comment: Great point.  You're absolutely right that my anwer is wrong in this context.

Comment: @Daniel - I'm not sure if I understand why the second example is "constant memory use", compared to the first.. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @ebb: I updated my answer with some details. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

> I need to first group the triples in the array into something like this:

If you know they will always be triples then representing then as a tuple `int * int * int` is more "typeful" than using an array because it conveys the fact that there are only ever exactly three elements.

Other people have described various ways to massage the data but I would actually recommend not bothering (unless there is more to this than you have described). I would opt for a function to destructure your array as-is instead:

```
let get i = a.[3*i], a.[3*i+1], a.[3*i+2]
```

If you really want to change the representation then you can now do:

```
let b = Array.init (a.Length/3) get
```

The answer really depends upon what you want to do next though...

Comment: Your simple "let get" is attractive to me because it doesn't require re-creating the entire set of original data, but merely provides a convenient way to look at the existing data. What are the performance implications of creating a tuple for each pixel get in the middle of a high performance processing loop?

Comment: @adamjcooper: You don't want to create tuples in the middle of high-performance loops. You might try using a `struct` type (value type) instead because it will avoid such heap allocations.

Answer (score 3):

(Hat tip: [Scott Wlaschin](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#13)) As of F# 4.0, you can use [`Array.chunkBySize()`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs#L574). It does exactly what you want:

```
let bs = [| 255;   0;   0; //Solid red
              0; 255;   0; //Solid green
              0;   0; 255; //Solid blue
              1;  72;   9; 
             34;  15; 155 |]
let grouped = bs |> Array.chunkBySize 3
// [| [|255;   0;   0|]
//    [|  0; 255;   0|]
//    [|  0;   0; 255|]
//    [|  1;  72;   9|]
//    [| 34;  15; 155|] |]
```

The `List` and `Seq` modules [also have `chunkBySize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33037477/424290) in F# 4.0. As of this writing, the docs at MSDN don't show `chunkBySize()` anywhere, but it's there **if** you're using F# 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by Daniel, this answer is wrong because it creates a sliding window.

You can use the `Seq.windowed` function from the library.  E.g.

```
let rgbPix = rawValues |> Seq.windowed 3
```

This returns a sequence rather than an array, so if you need random access, you could follow that with a call to `Seq.toArray`.

Comment: My next question was how to do the inverse of Seq.windowed, to flatten all of the sub arrays back into an array. Looks like you do this with **Seq.concat**.

Comment: you could do 'let rgbPix = rawValues |> Seq.windowed 3 |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (i,x)) |> Seq.filter (fun (a,_) -> a%3 = 0)' - but it would be pretrty inefficient

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, that takes and yields arrays directly:

```
let splitArrays n arr =
    match Array.length arr with
    | 0 ->
        invalidArg "arr" "array is empty"
    | x when x % n <> 0 ->
        invalidArg "arr" "array length is not evenly divisible by n"
    | arrLen ->
        let ret = arrLen / n |> Array.zeroCreate
        let rec loop idx =
            ret.[idx] <- Array.sub arr (idx * n) n
            match idx + 1 with
            | idx' when idx' <> ret.Length -> loop idx'
            | _                            -> ret
        loop 0
```

Or, yet another:

```
let splitArray n arr =
    match Array.length arr with
    | 0 ->
        invalidArg "arr" "array is empty"
    | x when x % n <> 0 ->
        invalidArg "arr" "array length is not evenly divisible by n"
    | arrLen ->
        let rec loop idx = seq {
            yield Array.sub arr idx n
            let idx' = idx + n
            if idx' <> arrLen then
                yield! loop idx' }
        loop 0 |> Seq.toArray
```