# Parallel processing N threads?

Tags: f#, parallel-processing, f#-3.0

**Clarified question:**

I have the following script which access web and local resources. I want to limit the web connections to N (the website is slow) and the local resources access (`executeLocalNetworkProcess`) shouldn't block other web requests. (So it will always run N web requests).

Some categories have very little items while others have a lot. The parallel execution should be run for all items of all categories to utilize the web connectdions.

```
let categories = getCategories() // get a seq of category from web service
for c in categories do
    getItemsByCategory c // returns a seq of item from web 
    |> Seq.iter (fun (item, _) -> // Want to process N items in parallel
        getMoreDataFromWeb item // from web
        executeLocalNetworkProcess item // local disk/network access; may take a while
        downloadBigFile item  // from web
        )
```

What's the best approach to implement it in F#?

Comment: What type is `items`? An array? Sequence? List?

Comment: [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx)?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : Er, how are you doing a for loop over a tuple or record?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to explicitly control the number of threads?  If I remember correctly, `Parallel.ForEach` will keep the number of threads within a reasonable limit.

Comment: I've updated the question based on the new question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar previously by splitting the sequence into batches of size `n` and processing the batch in parallel.

We can create batches of a sequence by using the code in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518857/2461791

From there we just need to iterate through the items in each batch in parallel. I like to put it in the `Array.Parallel` module.

```
module Array =
    module Parallel =
        let batchIter size action array =
            let batchesOf n =
                Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i / n, v) >>
                Seq.groupBy fst >>
                Seq.map snd >>
                Seq.map (Seq.map snd)

            for batch in array |> batchesOf size do 
                batch
                |> Seq.toArray    
                |> Array.Parallel.iter action
```

The following code splits a list of 100 items into batches of 8 and prints the items of each batch in parallel.

```
[1..100]
|> Array.Parallel.batchIter 8 (printfn "%d")
```

To apply this to your code, you're looking at something like this:

```
let categories = getCategories()
for c in categories do
    match c with | (category, description, _) -> printfn "%s" category
    getItemsByCategory c
    |> Array.Parallel.batchIter 8 (fun (item, description, _) ->
        process item
        )
```

This approach, however, will wait for an entire batch to finish processing before starting the next batch.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to include the [PSeq](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/blob/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq/pseq.fs) module source code from the F# PowerPack in your own foundation library. Then, you can simply call PSeq.iter:

```
for category, description, _ as c in getCategories() do
    printfn "%s" category
    getItemsByCategory c
    |> PSeq.iter(fun (item, description, _) -> process item)
```