# How to partition a list with a given group size?

Tags: list, f#

I'm looking for the best way to partition a list (or seq) so that groups have a given size.
for ex. let's say I want to group with size 2 (this could be any other number though):

```
let xs = [(a,b,c); (a,b,d); (y,z,y); (w,y,z); (n,y,z)]
let grouped = partitionBySize 2 input
// => [[(a,b,c);(a,b,d)]; [(y,z,y);(w,y,z)]; [(n,y,z)]]
```

The obvious way to implement partitionBySize would be by adding the position to every tuple in the input list so that it becomes

```
[(0,a,b,c), (1,a,b,d), (2,y,z,y), (3,w,y,z), (4,n,y,z)]
```

and then use GroupBy with

```
xs |> Seq.ofList |> Seq.GroupBy (function | (i,_,_,_) -> i - (i % n))
```

However this solution doesn't look very elegant to me.
Is there a better way to implement this function (maybe with a built-in function)?

Comment: In your example the Group inside the List (the commented line) is modeled as a Tuple. I guess you want it to be List i.e List inside List rather than Tuple as that would not be possible with static typing

Comment: Agree with Ankur. More even, the result you are expecting is not a valid F# value, because the last tuple is different from the rest. All items in a list should have the same type.

Comment: yup, sorry, that was what I meant, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tail-recursive function that traverses the list once.

```
let chunksOf n items =
  let rec loop i acc items = 
    seq {
      match i, items, acc with
      //exit if chunk size is zero or input list is empty
      | _, [], [] | 0, _, [] -> ()
      //counter=0 so yield group and continue looping
      | 0, _, _::_ -> yield List.rev acc; yield! loop n [] items 
      //decrement counter, add head to group, and loop through tail
      | _, h::t, _ -> yield! loop (i-1) (h::acc) t
      //reached the end of input list, yield accumulated elements
      //handles items.Length % n <> 0
      | _, [], _ -> yield List.rev acc
    }
  loop n [] items
```

Usage

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
|> chunksOf 2 
|> Seq.toList //[[1; 2]; [3; 4]; [5]]
```

I like the elegance of Tomas' approach, but I benchmarked both our functions using an input list of 10 million elements. This one clocked in at 9 secs vs 22 for his. Of course, as he admitted, the most efficient method would probably involve arrays/loops.

Comment: I'll pick this one but the other ones where pretty good too. Thanks all!

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a repeating pattern that's not captured by any function in the F# core library. When solving similar problems earlier, I defined a function `Seq.groupWhen` (see [F# snippets](http://fssnip.net/6A)) that turns a sequence into groups. A new group is started when the predicate holds.

You could solve the problem using `Seq.groupWhen` similarly to `Seq.group` (by starting a new group at even index). Unlike with `Seq.group`, this is efficient, because `Seq.groupWhen` iterates over the input sequence just once:

```
[3;3;2;4;1;2;8] 
|> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v) // Add indices to the values (as first tuple element)
|> Seq.groupWhen (fun (i, v) -> i%2 = 0) // Start new group after every 2nd element
|> Seq.map (Seq.map snd) // Remove indices from the values
```

Implementing the function directly using recursion is probably easier - the solution from John does exactly what you need - but if you wanted to see a more general approach then `Seq.groupWhen` may be interesting.

Comment: interesting. The most efficient solution so far.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori If you're looking for the most efficient solution, then I think that converting the input to an array and using slice `arr.[i .. i+n]` in a `for` loop is going to be the most efficient option.

Answer (score 5):

[`List.chunkBySize`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/4331dca3648598223204eed6bfad2b41096eec8a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fsi#L63) (hat tip: [Scott Wlaschin](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#13)) is now available and does exactly what you're talking about. It appears to be new with F# 4.0.

```
let grouped = [1..10] |> List.chunkBySize 3
// val grouped : int list list = 
//   [[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6]; [7; 8; 9]; [10]]
```

`Seq.chunkBySize` and `Array.chunkBySize` are also now available.

Answer (score 3):

What about a recursive approach? - only requires a single pass

```
let rec partitionBySize length inp dummy = 
    match inp with
    |h::t ->
        if dummy |> List.length < length then
            partitionBySize length t (h::dummy)
        else dummy::(partitionBySize length t (h::[]))
    |[] -> dummy::[]
```

Then invoke it with `partitionBySize 2 xs []`

Comment: result:[[(1, 2, 4); (1, 2, 3)]; [(5, 6, 7); (6, 7, 6)]], lost data

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Forgot to return the accumulator - should be fixed

Comment: very nice, the only downside is that it's not tail recursive and blows up with a large enough input (which by coincidence I have :-) )

Answer (score 2):

```
let partitionBySize size xs =
  let sq = ref (seq xs)
  seq {
    while (Seq.length !sq >= size) do
      yield Seq.take size !sq
      sq := Seq.skip size !sq
    if not (Seq.isEmpty !sq) then yield !sq
  }
  // result to list, if you want
  |> Seq.map (Seq.toList)
  |> Seq.toList
```

**UPDATE**

```
let partitionBySize size (sq:seq<_>) =
  seq {
    let e = sq.GetEnumerator()
    let empty = ref true;
    while !empty do
      yield seq { for i = 1 to size do
                    empty := e.MoveNext()
                    if !empty then yield e.Current
            }
  }
```

array slice version:

```
let partitionBySize size xs =
  let xa = Array.ofList xs
  let len = xa.Length
  [
    for i in 0..size..(len-1) do
      yield ( if i + size >= len then xa.[i..] else xa.[i..(i+size-1)] ) |> Array.toList 
  ]
```

Comment: I don't really understand why, but this is quite slow with my large dataSet (much slower than Tomas groupWhen)

Comment: This is slow because `Seq.skip` is inefficient, especially when you call it on a sequence that is already a result of `Seq.skip`. The returning sequence iterates over the original from the beginning, each time it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was late for the party. The code below is a tail-recursive version using high-order functions on `List`:

```
let partitionBySize size xs =
    let i = size - (List.length xs - 1) % size
    let xss, _, _ =
        List.foldBack( fun x (acc, ls, j) -> 
                                          if j = size then ((x::ls)::acc, [], 1) 
                                          else (acc, x::ls, j+1)
                       ) xs ([], [], i)
    xss
```

I did the same benchmark as Daniel did. This function is efficient while it is 2x faster than his approach on my machine. I also compared it with an array/loop version, they are comparable in terms of performance.

Moreover, unlike John's answer, this version preserves order of elements in inner lists.

Comment: I'd like to see your benchmark. In my test of 10M elements, mine is still a second faster.

Comment: I'm getting different results for initial and subsequent iterations. From a cold start, mine is faster. On subsequent runs yours is faster (by about 3 secs--still not 2x). Not sure what to attribute it to. This is in FSI.

Comment: Any idea why this function drops from 10 sec on a fresh FSI session to ~6 sec on subsequent runs? My function remains pretty much constant (~9 sec). Just wondering what could be different.

Comment: The results I got are from the benchmark with 1M elements. Don't know why there are some gaps between cold start and subsequent runs. Maybe there are some tricks behind implementation of List.foldBack?

Comment: Using 1M vs my 10M explains the discrepancy. The gap will narrow with larger inputs, and eventually tilt in my favor, since yours returns a list (the results are accumulated in memory) and mine returns a sequence (giving constant memory usage).

Comment: it will be difficult to choose a single answer. Excellent input by everybody!