# Equivalent of Ruby's Enumerable#each_slice method in FSharp

Tags: ruby, f#

I'm currently writing a bit of F#. I've created a method that is the equivalent of Ruby's `Enumerable#each_slice` method and was wondering if somebody has a better (i.e. more elegant, more concise, more readable) solution.

Here it is:

```
let rec slicesBySize size list =
    match list with
    | [] -> [] // case needed for type inference
    | list when list.Length < size -> [list]
    | _ ->
        let first = list |> Seq.take size |> List.ofSeq
        let rest = list |> Seq.skip size |> List.ofSeq

        [first] @ slicesBySize size rest
```

Thanks for any and all feedback/help.

Comment: Seems to be similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064016/how-to-partition-a-list-with-a-given-group-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`List.chunkBySize`](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/95fb299ab8588b112246f986148de9da8dbc9a4b/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L560-L568), which was added in F# 4.0. There are also `Seq` and `Array` variants.

Comment: I was looking at the F# docs and can't find where I specify the version of F# I want to use: 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx

I'm going to guess this is for F# 3.0 but I just can't find where I can specify F# 4.0

Comment: Yes, it appears MSDN hasn't been updated for F# 4.0 (thus my link to the source code).